# Azure Durable Function timeout exception

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Durable Function whose host.json file sets all functions to never timeout:
{
"version": "2.0",
"functionTimeout": "-1",
...
}
}

When the durable function is run though the activity function called by the orchestrator function gets a timeout after the default 30 minutes:

```
Timeout value of 00:30:00 was exceeded by function: LongRunningActivity
```

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException:
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__29.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 624)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)

The documentation states that the timeout defined in host.json should apply to all functions in the function app.

Have I missed something? Or is this a bug in Azure Durable Functions?